# Use of function execlp() in C

Tags: c, path, exec

I'm trying to use the function execlp() to make a child processes run a specific code that I wrote, but I don't understand how the path works.

NOTE: I use `export PATH=$PATH:.` in the terminal so I don't need to type `/.ProgName` every time.

The first program is:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <unistd.h>
main() {

    pid_t childpid; 
    int i;
    int nprocess = 3;
    for (i = 0; i < nprocess; ++i) {
     if ((childpid = fork()) < 0) {
         perror("fork:");
         exit(1);
     } 
     if (childpid==0){ 
        printf("I'm the son with ID= %ld\n",(long)getpid());
        char *path = "exectest";
        if ((execl(path,"0",NULL))<0) printf("\n error exec \n");
    } 
      else 
        printf("I'm the father with ID= %ld",(long)getpid());
    }

}
```

The second program to be called by the execlp is :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <time.h>


void main(){


        printf("\n I'm using exec \n");

}
```

Both programs are in the same directory. The second program is named "exectest" but when I launch the first, I get the error message.

Comment: You get what error message? If I compile these two programs, the second into an executable named "exectest" as your first program expects, I see output interleaved between the parent and three child processes, which does match your intent. The variable path is the pathname of the exec'd executable, not anything (directly) to do with $PATH.

Comment: "*NOTE: I use `export PATH=$PATH:.` in the terminal so I don't need to type `/.ProgName` every time.*" -- My advice: Don't do that; just type `./ProgName`. Having `.` in `$PATH` can open up security holes. At least having it at the *end* is safer than having it at the beginning, but if your program has the name name as any command anywhere in your `$PATH` (like `test`, for example), you won't be able to execute it without using `./` anyway. Get into the habit of being aware of whether a command is in the current directory, and use `./` if it is.

Comment: `@sjnarv` The error is the message in the `IF` statement where I call the execl function in case it returns a negative value, I would expect to see the message `"I'm using exec"` displayed but the first program runs normally and shows the error.

Comment: There are a few problems: 1) there are only two valid main declarations: int main(void) and int main( int argc, char* argv[])  2) the code is executing execl, not execlp. 3) the correct format is for an export is: export PATH = ${PATH}

Answer (score 0):

You should compile your second file `exectest.c` and get executable file which called `exectest`, because of your first program launch executable file `exectest`.